# Names for when you use hops

Tags: beer, hops, techniques

I have heard a lot about the different stages of hopping in the mash, but I have only heard the term dry hopping. Are there different terms given to the different stages of hopping, or are they all dry hopping?

Comment: Are you asking if there are different types (subsets) of "dry hopping" depending on when it's done? I.e. hops added to the fermenter or keg at different intervals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Brewtarget (brewing software):

- Mash hopping: adding hop in the mash
- First wort: adding hop in the boiling kettle and then lautering the wort in the kettle
- Boil: Adding hop when the wort boils, at different times
- Aroma: apparently adding hops after flameout, also called hop stand
- Dry hop of course, which is for someone who starts with brewing rather confusing, as you add hops always to a fluid. Also see [Dry hop etymology](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/dry-hop-etymology)

Comment: Still trying to figure out a real use for the first two options...

Comment: @barking.pete: When adding a real bittering hop in small quantities, I always use first wort hopping. Mash hopping is probably only needed when doing historical German beers.

Comment: @barking.pete: W.r.t. the previous comment, I don't brew big batches, and a couple of months ago I bought 1 kg hops. I came to the conclusion that I don't need to do first wort hopping anymore, because I must use at least 20 g of hop per brew if I want to expend that amount of hops within a year.

Comment: @barking.pete: W.r.t. first wort hopping, it was described in an Exbeeriment on Brülosophy, and I did use upon their recommendations: less chance of boil over, and smoother bittering.

Comment: Good answer. I would also add that "Wet Hop" or "Whole Hop" can modify any of these additions terms to mean using fresh harvest hops that have and have not been dried.

Comment: Many people break "boil" down into subcategories, such as the very clear "early" and "late" additions, and the slightly more obtuse "bittering", "flavour", and "aroma" additions.

Answer (score 3):

Dry hopping occurs post fermentation and includes all the aromatics and other volitales, but no bitter iso-alpha acids.

Bittering hops are added at various stages of the boiling process. At increased temperatures (145F min, 170F optimum) the alpha acids in hops are isomerized which increases the IBU of the beer. Some bittering hops are added at the beginning of a boil, some are added at various time intervals, some at flame out - this is because the temperature of the mash determines the rate of isomerization and lower temperatures will leave more volitale components. Some hops - such as Hallertau - are added near the end of the boil to evaporate undesireable flavors out of the hops.

Comment: The last part of the answer is something that I haven't seen mentioned anywhere else yet.

Comment: I stumbled upon that technique while researching classic trappist ale recipies, several of which called for Hallertau additions 15 minutes before flameout.

Answer (score 2):

I would expand a little on chthon's list, personally. Mine would look like this (these terms are in common usage in Australia, maybe less so elsewhere):

- Mash hopping: adding hop in the mash
- First wort: adding hop in the
  boiling kettle and then lautering the wort in the kettle
- Early or bittering: Adding hops to the boil in the first 10-20 minutes of the
  boil
- Middle or flavour: the same as above, but in the middle section
  of the boil late or
- Aroma: the same as above, but in the last 5
  minutes or so
- Flameout, hopstand or whirlpool: adding hops after the
  boil has finished. Can happen in the presence or absence of a
  whirlpool, at anywhere between about 30 degrees and boiling point.
  This does a similar job to dry hopping, but due to higher
  termperatures, extracts more compounds
- Dry hop:adding hops to fermented beer

Mash hopping can be handy if you're dealing with a large volume of flower hops that you might otherwise first wort with. They would take up a lot of space, and soak up a lot of wort in  the kettle, and be that extra bit harder to clean out. Sticking them in the mash is quite convenient.

First wort is also great, getting you arguably higher utilisation and a smoother bitterness. I only use first wort for bittering now, I don't do any early bittering additions in the boil.

Hop stands around 60 celsius are marvelous for very hop forward beers, you can really load the character up.

Answer (score 1):

Dry hopping refers to adding hops in the fermentation vessel.  Using a mesh bag or not.  During or at end of fermentation.  Hops is removed before bottling or after a certain number of days.  This technique is mostly used for flavoring.

The most common hopping is during boil, where the number of minutes is used to know when to add the hops to the wort.  This technique is used for bittering (early addition) and flavoring (late addition).